# Dockerfile finishing with 'No space on device error'

Tags: azure, docker, dockerfile

I had a dockerfile which was working absolutely fine. Suddenly, I start getting this error:

```
ApplyLayer exit status 1 stdout:  stderr: write /opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/lib/libtorch_cuda.so: no space left on device
##[error]ApplyLayer exit status 1 stdout:  stderr: write /opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/lib/libtorch_cuda.so: no space left on device
##[error]The process '/usr/bin/docker' failed with exit code 1
```

I am not sure how to fix this. I tried `docker prune` in the docerfile but get the same error. Any help please?

Comment: Your image is too big for your available disk space. Build a smaller image or get more available disk space.

Answer (score 1):

Your docker hard drive space is low.
You can increase the space for docker or delete data with the command:

```
docker system prune
```

Output:

```
WARNING! This will remove:
  - all stopped containers
  - all networks not used by at least one container
  - all dangling images
  - all dangling build cache

Are you sure you want to continue? [y/N]
```

You type `y` to accept.